Why my docker container does not see a NFS mountpoint defined as a volume?
I am setting up my Jellyfin server on docker.
I correctly mounted my NFS on /net_storage/media on my host machine, and I am able to see all the files.
Then, i created my docker compose file:
---
services:
  jellyfin:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jellyfin:latest
    container_name: jellyfin
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - JELLYFIN_PublishedServerUrl=192.168.0.5 #optional
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /net_storage/media/tv_series:/data/tvshows
      - /net_storage/media/movies:/data/movies
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
    restart: unless-stopped


But, once the container started, i noticed that /data/tvshows and /data/movies were empty.
Already tried to run chmod -R 755 /net_storage/media but nothing changed.
